# What are the length limits of the profile fields?

Tags: support, profile-page, character-limit

There are some limits on some fields, for example 'Donaudampfschifffahrtselektrizitätenhauptbetriebswerkbauunterbeamtengesellschaft' is too long for the user name (although not too long for real name, in spite of not being real).

However, I've failed to Google it, what are the limits for the fields in profile on the Stack Exchange network?

Do you them documented somewhere?

Comment: [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) does...

Comment: Is there an actual problem you are facing or some practical use to this? Clearly the code could change and documenting it externally seems like a low payback item for the developers.

Answer (score 4):

Taken from [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/):

> DisplayName    nvarchar (40)
> WebsiteUrl  nvarchar (200)
> Location    nvarchar (100)
> AboutMe nvarchar (max) (but see below)

So, in plain words:

1. "Display name" is limited to 40 characters
2. "Website" is limited to 200 characters
3. "Location" is limited to 100 charactrs
4. "About Me" is not limited in database, but there is a "soft" limit of 3000 characters. If you try to go over that the form submission fails.

As for "real name" it's not part of SEDE so need to find other means to check its capacity.

Comment: Thanks Monica, missed the obvious - glad to see hats are useful. ;)